# default vlan span status

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, vlan

the correct result of vlan spanning status is like this:

```
import SoftLayer
username='xxxxxx'
key='xxxxxx'
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=username, api_key=key, timeout=600)
account = client['Account']
account.getNetworkVlanSpan()
{'lastVerifiedDate': '2018-04-19T22:02:23-05:00', 'modifyDate': '2018-04-19T22:02:23-05:00', 'enabledFlag': True, 'lastAppliedDate': '2018-04-19T20:45:27-05:00', 'id': xxxxx}
```

while I found in a new created account, before I choose vlan spanning status on web portal, result of account.getNetworkVlanSpan() will be an empty dict. is this right? In this situation, what is the default status of vlan span, on or off ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is right it is empty, by default the devices located on different private VLANs can not send traffic to each other, it is a restriction or protection that private VLANs have.

In this situation the default status of vlan span is off.

For more information you can see the following documentation:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/vlans/getting-started.html#getting-started-with-vlans